# Requesting resource from URLClassLoader results in "zip file closed" exception

Tags: java, url, classloader

I am working with an application that regularly requests resources from a `URLClassLoader` via the `getResourceAsStream` method. For some resources (that do not exist) this causes the following exception instead of returning `null`:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: zip file closed
        at java.util.zip.ZipFile.ensureOpen(ZipFile.java:669)
        at java.util.zip.ZipFile.getEntry(ZipFile.java:309)
        at java.util.jar.JarFile.getEntry(JarFile.java:240)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.jar.URLJarFile.getEntry(URLJarFile.java:128)
        at java.util.jar.JarFile.getJarEntry(JarFile.java:223)
        at sun.misc.URLClassPath$JarLoader.getResource(URLClassPath.java:1005)
        at sun.misc.URLClassPath$JarLoader.findResource(URLClassPath.java:983)
        at sun.misc.URLClassPath.findResource(URLClassPath.java:188)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$2.run(URLClassLoader.java:569)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$2.run(URLClassLoader.java:567)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findResource(URLClassLoader.java:566)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.getResource(ClassLoader.java:1093)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.getResource(ClassLoader.java:1088)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.getResource(ClassLoader.java:1088)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.getResourceAsStream(ClassLoader.java:1304)
```

As exposed by Google, this error seems to be fairly common and the often named cause is a broken jar file what is very unlikely in my case. Could this be a bug in the VM or is there another known but undocumented reason for why this can happen? It seems like this should never be the outcome when calling the `getResourceAsStream` method.